# Linearly independent matrix proof

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

Suppose that $S=\{u_1,u_2,…,u_n\}$ is a set of vector from $\mathbb{R}^m$. Show that $S$ is linearly independent if and only if the set $S'=\left\{u_1,\ \sum_{i=1}^2 u_i,\ \sum_{i=1}^3 u_i,\ \ldots,\ \sum_{i=1}^n u_i\right\}$ is linearly independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If S is a linear independent set, then $a_1u_1+a_2u_2+...+a_nu_n=0$ implies all $a_i=0$ by definition. Thus
$$b_1u_1+b_2\sum_i^2u_i+...+b_n\sum_i^nu_i=\sum_i^nb_iu_1+\sum_i^{n-1}b_iu_2+...+b_nu_n=0$$
implies $\sum_i^kb_i=0$ for all $k$, namely $b_i=0$ for all $i$. That is, S' is also a linear independent set.

The reverse direction is similar and easy now.

Answer (score 0):

Define

$$s_k := \sum_{i=1}^k u_i, \quad k=1:n.$$

Then $S' = \{ s_1, s_2, \dots, s_n \}$. Note that

$$u_1 = s_1, \quad u_k = s_k - s_{k-1}, \quad k > 1.$$

This should be enough to get you going. If you get stuck, write what you did and explain where is the problem.